# Loading a script by name in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game in C# with Unity3D and I need to call a script that I create on runtime, so I know the name of the script because I have an object named exactly like it.

I create the script on runtime and then I save it to my Resources folder, but then I change the scene and need to call that script and attach it to my Empty GameObject in the current scene, so I would like to use something like that:

```
Script myScript = Resources.Load(myObject.name) as Script;
```

But I know this can't be done like this, so I'm looking for a way I can do what I want, because I need to load that new script to add some functions on runtime.

Do you know any solution to my problem? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's actually easier than you think. You can add a script to a game object using the AddComponent method. So after your level has changed you can just get hold of your empty game object and do a:

```
var gameObject = ... 

gameObject.AddComponent<Script>(); // where Script is the name of your Script's C# class
```

See http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

Comment: Well I can do that in the editor, but when I build the project it throws an error.

The problem is that I create a .cs file with FileStream.WriteFile() in runtime, so that file doesn't exist like a class as itself when I build the project. THe fact is that in the Unity editor I can do that but when I build the project, it throws the error "Can't add component because class 'myClass' doesn't exist!"

Comment: You write that class while your game is running? What exactly are you trying to achieve with this? Maybe there is another way to do it. Could you give some insights on why you need to create that class at runtime?

Answer (score -1):

```
    GameObject gameObj = new GameObject();
    Type scriptType = Type.GetType(nameSpace.className);
    if (scriptType == null)
    {
        foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            var tempType = a.GetType(nameSpace.className);
            if (tempType != null)
            {
                scriptType = tempType;
            }
        }
    }
    gameObj.AddComponent(scriptType);
```

Comment: Even ignoring the complete lack of explanation or elaboration that would make this an answer instead of just a code dump, why in the world would anyone consider this a viable option, when there's a perfectly good generic method available to do the job in a much simpler, more efficient manner?